# Можно ли средствами CMD создавать файлы MS Office?

Tags: cmd, bat

Здравствуйте!

Пишу скрипт для автоматизации создания проектов, где вложены некие каталоги, внутри которых другие подкаталоги. В определенном каталоге хотелось бы автоматически создавать файлы Microsoft Office. Если возможно, то в свойствах документа дописывать при создании автора, название и тему.

Можно ли средствами CMD создавать файлы MS Office? Например, *.doc или *.xls? Если нельзя, то какие инструменты (скриптовые языки, например VBScript) для этого можно использовать?

Comment: Можно при помощи PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попытаться сгенерировать документы при помощи скрипта `PowerShell`.

Пример создания Word-документа:

```
  $savepath="C:\work\MyDoc.docx"
  $word=new-object -ComObject "Word.Application"
  $doc=$word.documents.Add()
  $selection=$word.Selection
  #вставка текста
  $selection.TypeText((Get-Date))
  #вставка конца абзаца
  $selection.TypeParagraph()
  #вставка еще текста
  $os=Get-WmiObject -class win32_OperatingSystem
  $selection.TypeText("Operating System Information for $($os.CSName)")
  #получение свойств документа
  $os.properties | select Name | foreach -begin {$props=@()} -proc {$props+="$($_.name)"}
  #вывод их в документ как текст
  $selection.TypeText(($os | Select -Property $props | Out-String))
  $doc.SaveAs([ref]$savepath)    
  $doc.Close()
  $word.quit()
```

Вот тут можно найти пример задания свойств документа:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781428/how-to-change-custom-properties-for-many-word-documents

Answer (score 0):

Создавать сложно. Зато можно скопировать образец с любым расширением.